# rank of the free group: $\mathrm{rank} F_X=|X|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question is an extension of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35229/free-groups-f-x-cong-f-y-rightarrowx-y).

Let $F_X$ denote the free group on the set $X$. For any group $G$ and subset $S\!\subseteq\!G$, $\langle S\rangle$ denotes the subgroup generated by $S$ and $\mathrm{rank}(G) :=\min\{|S|;\:S\!\subseteq\!G, \langle S\rangle\!=\!G\}$.

**PROPOSITION:**
**a)** $F_X\cong F_Y\:\Leftrightarrow\:|X|=|Y|$
**b)** $\mathrm{rank}(F_X)=|X|$

Thus for every cardinal number $c$, there is (up to isomorphism) exactly one free group of rank $c$.

**Proof:**

**a)** $(\Leftarrow)$: If $f\!:X\rightarrow Y$ is the bijection, then $\varphi(x_1\ldots x_k):=f(x_1)\ldots f(x_k)$ is the isomorphism.

$(\Rightarrow)$: $F_X\!\cong\!F_Y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathrm{Ab} F_X\!\cong\!\mathrm{Ab} F_Y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\oplus_{x\in X}\mathbb{Z}\!\cong\!\oplus_{y\in Y}\mathbb{Z}$, so $|X|\!=\!|Y|$, since rank is known to be an invariant of free modules.

Alternatively, $\big(\oplus_{x\in X}\mathbb{Z}\big)\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$ $\cong$ $\oplus_{x\in X}\big(\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}\big)$ $\cong$ $\oplus_{x\in X}\mathbb{Q}$, so $\oplus_{x\in X}\mathbb{Q}$ $\cong$ $\oplus_{y\in Y}\mathbb{Q}$, even as $\mathbb{Q}$-modules, but isomorphic vector spaces are known to have equipollent bases.

**b)** Since $\langle X\rangle\!=\!F_X$, $\mathrm{rank}(F_X)\leq|X|$. Suppose we have $Y\!\subseteq\!F_X$, $\langle Y\rangle\!=\!F_X$, $|Y|\!<\!|X|$.

**QUESTION:** how can I finish the proof of **b)**, i.e. prove that $F_X$ can't be generated by a subset with smaller cardinality than $|X|$?

Comment: Abelianizing and tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ still works.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Hmm, I'm confused. Abelianizing what? $F_Y$? How do I prove $F_Y=F_X$?

Comment: You don't. The hypothesis implies that a vector space of dimension $|Y|$ surjects onto a vector space of dimension $|X|$, which is already enough to conclude.

Comment: @Qiaochu: how exactly do I get a vector space? $(\mathrm{Ab}\langle Y\rangle)\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$? How do I know this has rank $|Y|$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the argument written out in full so you can tell me which step you don't understand. Suppose $F_X$ is generated by a subset $Y$ with $|Y| < |X|$. This induces a surjection $F_Y \to F_X$. Abelianization gives a surjection $\text{Ab}(F_Y) \to \text{Ab}(F_X)$. Tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ gives a surjection from a vector space of dimension $|Y|$ to a vector space of dimension $|X|$; contradiction.

Comment: Ah, now it makes perfect sense. The problem I had was that I didn't know what you were abelianising, $F_Y$ or $\langle Y\rangle$; I constantly had the feeling that I was implicitly assuming the thing I was proving. Just one more detail, the map $F_Y\rightarrow F_X$ is actually tne inclusion, since $Y\subseteq X$, right?

Comment: @Leon: I'm not assuming $Y \subseteq X$; that wouldn't solve the problem. I'm just assuming $Y \subseteq F_X$ generates it. (Ah, I was confused by your notation $\langle Y \rangle$: I thought this meant $F_Y$, but you meant the subgroup of $F_X$ generated by $Y$. Which confuses me, because this is just $F_X$.)

Comment: Ah, $Y\subseteq X$ was stupid remark, sorry. $\langle Y\rangle$ means subgroup generated by $Y$ and $F_Y$ means free group on the alphabet $Y$. But why would $F_Y$ equal $\langle Y\rangle$? After all, $F_X=\langle F_X\rangle$, but $F_{F_X}\ncong F_X$. Anyway, $F_Y$ is a group of **words on words on $X$**. So the homomorphism $F_Y\to F_Y$ takes **words on words on $X$** to **words on $X$**. I think I get the picture now.

Comment: @Leon: I was confused about what $\langle Y \rangle$ meant. And yes, that's right. There's an interesting way to think about how to write down a group structure on a set $G$ related to this: it's equivalent to providing a map $F_G \to G$ satisfying certain requirements spelled out by the axioms of a [monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)).

Comment: thanks man, I appreciate it. And sorry for my confusions... Oh, and just one more thing, do we really have to go to vector spaces (i.e. tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$), or do free modules provide the answer? *Can there be a surjection from a free module with smaller rank to a free module with greater rank?*

Comment: @Leon: over general rings, yes. The property that ranks of free modules behave the way you expect them to is known as the [invariant basis number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) property. Obviously every ring that embeds into a division ring (such as $\mathbb{Z}$) has IBN by tensoring. I think it is known that every commutative ring has IBN. But commutative algebra is difficult and I prefer to reduce to linear algebra whenever possible.