# Isomorphic free groups $F(A),F(B)$ induce bijective sets $A \cong B$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help trying to solve this problem.
Let $A, B$ be sets, and $F(A), F(B)$ the corresponding free groups. Assume $F(A) \cong F(B)$. If $A$ is finite, prove that so is $B$, and $A \cong B$ as sets.

Comment: Please explain the notation ~=.

Comment: it means it is an isomorphism.

Comment: The same question for *arbitrary set* (not necessarily *finite*) has been asked here: [free groups: $F_X\cong F_Y\Rightarrow|X|=|Y|$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35229/free-groups-f-x-cong-f-y-rightarrowx-y)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets.  If the free groups $F(A)$ and $F(B)$ are isomorphic, so are their abelianizations.  The abelianizations are the free *abelian* groups on the sets $A$ and $B$.  It is much easier to see that if these are isomorphic, then $\# A \cong \# B$: for instance tensor with $\mathbb{Q}$ to reduce to the fact that bases of isomorphic vector spaces have the same cardinality.

Comment: Someone has to upvote this answer at some point, +1. Interestingly, [point 3 here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Facts_and_theorems) claims that it follows readily from the definition.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the downvote here: what seems to be amiss?